# How to save XML GET response to file in PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, get, phantomjs

I want to save a GET response to a file. This is my code:

```
function(){
    var page=require('webpage').create();
    var callback=function(status){
        if (status=='success'){  
            page.render('pic1.png');   
            var fs = require('fs');
            fs.write('reppo.xml',page.content,'w')
            console.log('Got report...');
        }else{
            console.log('Failed to load.');
        }
    };

    var url =  "https://10.84.163.146/event_stream/events_in_xml?events=137,138&arow=902&noxsl=y&nonmal=y";
    page.open(url,callback);   
},
```

I expect a XML document as answer. When i put the link directly in my browser, everything works fine but when i execute the script i get a file that contains the following code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><body><parsererror style="display: block; white-space: pre; border: 2px solid #c77; padding: 0 1em 0 1em; margin: 1em; background-color: #fdd; color: black"><h3>This page contains the following errors:</h3><div style="font-family:monospace;font-size:12px">error on line 1 at column 0: Encoding error</div><h3>Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.</h3></parsererror></body></html>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

try changing your user agent. I know in PHP if I don't do this some websites block access. Add this code right after initing webpage.
page.settings.userAgent = 'Chrome/28.0.1500.71';